# Build regular expression for replacing duplicated string into single word

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working of filtering comments. I'd like to replace string like this:

```
llllolllllllllllooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuudddddddddddddd
```

with two words: `lol loud`

---

string like this:

`cuytwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww`

with: `cuytw`

---

And string like this:

`hyyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyu`

with: `hyu`

---

but not modify strings like look, geek.
Is there any way to achieve this with single regular expression in C#?

Comment: Any reasons for downwote?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you could define better input and output

Comment: Why would it go down to `loud` - it looks more like `loloudloloudloloudloloud`

Comment: `loud` is dictionary word but what about `cuntw` and `hyu`? What is your requirement?

Comment: I think this would have to employ a good deal of harry potter magic, if not a dictionary

Comment: @Saruman I thought you were a Wizard, use your magic! ;)

Comment: LOL, LOUD! :)))

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy i think you need to think about this and better define your examples. at the moment there are too many degrees of freedom that wont fit your desired output

Comment: You could remove repeated characters with [`(.)\1{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/6GLIqU/1), and then match [`(.+)(?=\1$)`](https://regex101.com/r/0s1iBu/1), the repeating word will be the last match.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes wouldn't this modify _look_ and _geek_ which the OP doesn't want to change?

Comment: Let me save you the suspense. Due to second requirement, it's not possible with Regular Expressions. Don't blow your mind.

Comment: @Magnetron. No, `(.)` match one character, and `\1{2,}` requires two more of the first character... this means at least three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can answer this categorically.

This definitely cant be done with `RegEx` or even standard code due to your input and output requirements without at minimum some sort of dictionary and algorithm to try and reduce doubles in a permutation check for legitimate words.

The result (at best) would give you a list of possible non mutually-exclusive combinations of nonsense words and legitimate words with doubles.

In fact, I'd go as far to say with your current requirements and no extra specificity on rules, your input and output are generically impossible and could only be taken at face value for the cases you have given.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to use RegEx for this problem, but here is an alternative which is arguably easier to read.<sup>*</sup>

Assuming you just want to return a string comprising the distinct letters of the input in order, you can use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501):

```
private static string filterString(string input)
{
    var groups = input.GroupBy(c => c);
    var output = new string(groups.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray());
    return output;
}
```

Passes:

- Returns `loud` for `llllolllllllllllooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuddddddddddddddllllollllllllllllloooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuudddddddddddddd`
- Returns `cuytw` for `cuytwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww`
- Returns `hyu` for `hyyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyuyu`

Failures:

- Returns `lok` for `look`
- Returns `gek` for `geek`

---

<sup>*</sup> On second read you want to leave words like `look` and `geek` alone; this is a *partial* answer.

Comment: It won't for the second criteria "_but not modify strings like look, geek_"

Comment: Good point. I've modified my answer to state that's it's a partial answer. I thought about taking the last key (character) in the grouping and returning the substring to the first index of that character, but that would fail on the more complicated cases which currently work.